# How do I make this command run in the background

Tags: windows, dos

```
– ping www.google.com –t
```

I have created a shortcut on desktop and typed this command as it's "Target " ..Now when I double click it, cmd window opens for a sec and vanishes..how do I make it run in the background until this process is manually ended ? The shortcut name's "Ping" and I don't see no Process named "Ping" in the task manager. What I want is to keep on pinging google server

Comment: Thanks to both for answering...I found the solution here...http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/run-bat-files-invisibly-without-displaying-command-prompt/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Do a manual ping from the command prompt and write a -t at the end which makes it a persistent ping. You would have to close the cmd prompt window to stop the ping.

for example type in command prompt: `ping www.google.com -t`

**Solution 2:**
you can create a shortcut like so

```
cmd /c "ping www.google.com –t"
```

**Solution 3:**
Any free ping utility would do what you require, check on google for "free ping" which will also
work.

**PK**

Comment: ok ran the command manually..it is pinging but msg like "Request Timed out" in between ..what does this mean ?

Comment: Also when I created that shortcut like u said..it dsplayed cmd window for a sec saying "Bad parameter -t" This is what Target value is System32\cmd.exe /c "ping www.google.com –t"  Is this correct ??

Comment: Ping request timed out...  The address was found but it isn't responding to ping requests. nothing wrong with your system. so dont worry.

Comment: ok try it without the t. just make sure you run it in cmd instead.

Comment: The shortcut's not running..what should be the target value ?

Comment: I typed the command manually only when got that msg saying "Request Timed out"..what I want is this command to run in the background..don't want no cmd window open or minimized on my desktop

Comment: http://www.realgeek.com/forums/setting-up-ping-as-a-service-in-background-403727.html

Comment: I have no frikkin idea how those scripts work..lol..but anyways thanks

Answer (score 2):

set Target as: `%windir%\system32\ping.exe www.google.com -t`

and Start in: `%windir%`

[EDIT]

TO Hide a cmd window

```
        using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
```

In main

```
        IntPtr hWnd = FindWindow(null, "ping");
        if (hWnd != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            ShowWindow(hWnd, 0);
        }
```

To Unhide

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, 1);
```

Comment: Can I recommend you using c# program ?

Comment: sure..will it take less of memory space ??

Comment: It would not take much memory. You can do that whole thing by c# program without use ping exe at all. Should I give you that c# code or give u the code which will hide the ping cmd screen ?